# Pegar id auto incremento de duas tabelas unidas (INNER JOIN)

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, id

Vamos ver se eu consigo explicar de primeira...

tenho duas tabelas [topicos] e [notification]

eu uni essas tabelas com INNER JOIN para obter os dados de ambas, até aí tudo bem...

porém quando eu preciso selecionar o [id] da tabela [notification] no while, mas só me retorna o [id] da tabela [topicos], como posso recuperar o id de ambos nesse select?

Segue meu SELECT:

```
SELECT notification.*, topicos.* FROM notification INNER JOIN topicos ON notification.user = "USUARIO_TAL"
```

Comment: a chave primaria das duas tabelas é `id`?

Comment: sim a chave primaria das duas é [id].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é você listar as colunas que interessam uma a uma, em vez de usar `*`. Aí você pode definir um *alias* pra cada uma se necessário. Por exemplo:

```
SELECT
    notification.id AS notification_id,
    topicos.id AS topico_id
...
```

No seu `while` (em php, pelo que você disse), você pode se referir ao id pelo alias, no caso `notification_id` ou `topico_id`.

Comment: entendi, porém são muitos campos não gostaria de deixar o codigo muito maior nesse caso, como posso recuperar a variavel dentro do while?

Comment: Bom, nada te impede de fazer `SELECT notification.*, notification.id AS notification_id` etc

Comment: entendi, porém na hora de listar os ids dentro do while não consigo recuperar ambos os ids, se eu fizer while ($dados = $select->fetch()){$dados['id']} ele retorna o primeiro mas o segundo não..

Comment: conseguir resolver, fiz o select conforme me disse setando ALIAs para os campos e na hora de recuperar no while eu chamo o campo do alias a invés do campo original, obrigado aí bfavaretto

Comment: Isso, desculpe, devia ter explicado essa parte. Vou editar a resposta para deixar completa.